# Cron not appending to file correctly

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, cron

I have a script (logtemps.sh) that logs the temperature of my Raspberry Pi, as follows

```
TIME1=$(date +%s)
TEMP1=$(</sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)
sleep 1s

TIME2=$(date +%s)
TEMP2=$(</sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)
sleep 1s

TIME3=$(date +%s)
TEMP3=$(</sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)
sleep 1s

echo "$TIME1,$TEMP1"
echo "$TIME2,$TEMP2"
echo "$TIME3,$TEMP3"
```

Running `./logtemps.sh` gives (for example):

```
1499618156,55843
1499618157,56382
1499618158,55843
```

This is as planned.

I have a cronjob set up to run this every other minute, and append the output into a file `temps.txt` using
`*/2 * * * * /home/pi/temp-cron/logtemps.sh >> /home/pi/temp-cron/temps.txt 2>&1`.

However, when I look at `temps.txt` it gives

```
1499618041,
1499618042,
1499618043,
1499618161,
1499618162,
1499618163,
```

The second variable ($TEMPn) seems to be completely ignored.

The cronjob was installed with `crontab -e`, so it should be run as my user (`pi`), so I don't see where any difference would come from not running it myself.

Answer (score 1):

In `logtemps.sh` I make use of `$(<file)` to read the contents of `file` into a variable. This is a feature of **bash**, however cron executes commands with **sh**. To solve this, either change the line in crontab to

`*/2 * * * * bash /home/pi/temp-cron/logtemps.sh >> /home/pi/temp-cron/temps.txt 2>&1`

(added `bash`)

or add `#!/bin/bash` to the top of the script so that it will always execute under `bash`.

See [benefit 4)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_Ritchie) of the update to Version 8 Unix, where the #! was introducted.

TLDR; Cron executes under `sh`, script used `bash`-only commands, always shebang.

Comment: You could also add `SHELL=/bin/bash` to your crontab file. This changes `crontab`'s default shell from `sh` to `bash`.